# Laravel 5.3 image upload issue

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel 5.3. I need to upload the image to the database table spare. Here is my controller. The error i am getting is also attached.Please help thanks in advance.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $Spare=new Spares;
        $Spare->model_id=$request->get('modelId');
        $Spare->brand_id=$request->get('brandId');
        $Spare->partNumber=$request->get('partNumber');
        $Spare->warranty=$request->get('warranty');
        $Spare->retailer_id=$request->get('retailerId');
        $Spare->quantity=$request->get('quantity');
        $Spare->price=$request->get('price');
        $Spare->description=$request->get('description');
        $file = $request->file('image');

        // Get the contents of the file
        $contents = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());

        $Spare->image=$contents;

        $Spare->save();
        \Session::flash('flash_message','Added new Spare.'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){
        dd($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

[image]

Comment: adding to the above answers always validate that you actually have a file, so in this case when you dont have you have a error cause $file is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the HTML for this form I'll take a guess that your `<form>` tag is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. This attribute is required for uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`for any kind of file uploads. Even if you are not using laravel you need to put the attribute and value as `multipart/form-data`.

You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)